# weird code in my host "stole my ID database"

Tags: encryption, crypt

I found a weird code in my host, and when I saw log of this code, I found this

root:*E5477F9455DBFB1F9E1056380CACEEEF1520B4FE:www
root:*E12712B455DBFB1F9E1226380CACBFAF1520B4FE:127.0.0.1
root:*E1471FB455DBFB1F9E10063380CAEFAF1520B4FE:
phpmyadmin:*E1477FB455DBFB1F9E1006380CACEFAF1520B4FE:localhost

I would like to know what kind of cryptage is it ? plz

sha256 i think